# When to use the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm serving a semi-static site with rails, just to get used to rails conventions.
Do I really need to use the asset pipeline to serve the .css and .js?
I could always precompile my .scss and coffee-script before their on the server.
and by semi-static, I mean that I may include some gems to do syntax highlighting or some other little tasks.
I guess it would be good practice?
I'm super new to rails and programming in general, by the way.
I just want another opinion.
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the asset pipeline if you are using rails 3.1 or above.  It is far faster than the previous serving of assets in rails -- among other things, it munges and minifies the files.

You should always precompile your assets in production, whether or not you are using straight .css or .scss because if you don't precompile your assets, rails will still have to compile them at runtime.

Comment: good advice, I actually started adding everything to the pipline, although I am having a problem with images in my .scss files, but I'll figure it out, thanks.

Comment: the sass-rails gem has helpers for image paths and urls: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails